# scheduled chkdsk on Windows 7 blinking the hard disk light every 5 seconds, what can I do?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

PG&E (the local electricity company) came and took out the old power meters and put in a new ones by brute force and with no advance notice in our neighborhood, so my computer went down in power.

So I went to Windows 7's drive C and schedule a Disk Cleanup (chkdsk) on the next boot up.

When it boots up, it says

```
A disk check has been scheduled
To skip disk checking, press any key within __ second(s).
```

and then after it shows

```
To skip disk checking, press any key within 1 second(s).
```

it just sits there, with no further message.  the hard disc light blinks every 5 seconds.  So what is to be done now?  I certainly don't want to brute force power off again.

Comment: What happens if you press a key immediately when the message appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to run the chkdsk via a different method to overcome the issue you are experiencing at this time.

You need to boot up with your Windows CD and select repair to access the Recovery Console.
Then you can run "chkdsk /r" from the prompt.

For more details about the Recovery Console see [Improved Recovery Options in Windows 7](http://www.notebooks.com/2009/10/20/improved-recovery-options-in-windows-7/).

Comment: Good suggestion, but didn't resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this same issue, and it was *not* resolved by running a chkdsk through the recovery console - that check ran fine, but the same problem presented upon reboot.

However, I was able to resolve the issue - try removing all peripherals except for your keyboard from your machine and rebooting. Unplugging my second keyboard, mouse, and usb sound card solved the issue for me - chkdsk ran normally after boot and the disk was subsequently flagged as clean.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has confirmed this to be a bug in Win7. When some files are moved, the 'tmp' version overwirtes part of the file which results in a corrupt error flag being set. The file is intact, i.e. no error, but chkdsk is scheduled to run at next boot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to upvote this, but Zxaos is right, unplugging your peripherals solved it for me. I unplugged my main keyboard, and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is experiencing this problem. There are no additional peripherals plugged in. I believe the constant hdd activity gives me about a 45 min. battery life...I just got the laptop.